# asp:DropDownList selectedvalues in multiple selection list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqldatasource, selectlist

I have asp:DropDownList wich is populated from SQLdatasource and I need to set selected items on select list (asp:DropDownList or asp:DropDownList).

Here is my code:

```
      <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sqlAihealueet"
 ConnectionString="Server=SQL2008;Database=Data;UID=123;PWD=123"
  SelectCommand="SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT valikkoaktiivinen, alue, id, otsikko, osa1b, osa2b, osa3b, osa4b FROM            dbo.FiValikko"></asp:SqlDataSource>

  <asp:DropDownList  name="aihevalinta" id="aihevalinta"  multiple="true" DataSourceid="sqlAihealueet" DataValueField="id" DataTextField="otsikko"  class="populate placeholder"  style="width:450px; font-size:11px" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

On this page I have all other fields set up on codebehind like this:

```
vapaaselite.text = drRow.Item("vapaaselitetxt").ToString
```

How should I make that multiple selected ones to that select list on?

I have tryed this (aihealueet data = "9682,9683"):

```
aihevalinta.SelectedValues = drRow.Item("aihealueet")
```

not working, gives me error: SelectedValues' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList

Is there way I could make selecteced items straight from  sql datasource, from SQLquery? I could mark them easily on SQLquery.

...or how Do I do this with asp:Listbox? I tryed same kind of aproach. I only can get one item as selected. If I try to make other one selected too the first selected ones select state disappears.

```
aihevalinta.SelectedValue = "9565"
aihevalinta.SelectedValue = "9566"
```

[image]

The best solution for me would be to mark selected one straigt from SQldatasource (same where the list comes form). data would be like this:

[image]

Comment: It's not completely clear what you are asking, but if you are trying to select multiple items in a DropDownList, you can't. A [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx) may be more appropriate.

Comment: ASP .NET DropDownList does not have properties like 'multiple' or SelectedValues it only allows you to select 1 item. There are custom web controls available that can do this like Telerik drop down list or Ajax combo box.

Comment: @All  it is not straight forward but it is possible making the multiple items in one item.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you would like to fill your DropDownList with multiple values, something like this:
[image]

It is possible, I do it in this way:

Markup:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Code behind:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            con.Open();
            str = "select * from Pagamenti ORDER BY [Data] DESC";
            com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            ds = new DataSet();
            sqlda.Fill(ds, "Pagamenti");
            string spacer = "   --|--   ";
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0:Id ####}", ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Id"]) +
                                        spacer + Convert.ToDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Data"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") +
                                        spacer + string.Format("{0:R #.###,##}", (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Somma"])));
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

Let us know if this is what you where looking for.

Comment: I looking for solution to make multiple items as selected. at the end html on select would be like this:
<option value="512">Oy aaaa bbbb Ab (ddddja.fi)</option>
<option selected="selected" value="492">Oy ddddd (Rdd.fi)</option>
<option selected="selected" value="451">reed Oy (Rdd.fi)</option>

Comment: The best solution would be to make selected straight from the DataSource. For example i could make SQL query where there would be one data column to as selected = 1 or selected = 0

Comment: @Timo77 absolutely not clear what you are looking for. Update your question and try to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make work around to my problem. I'am sure there have to some better way to do this.

My work around were done using some jquery script and non visible asp.net textbox field (valinnatlista).

```
<script>

var data= $("#valinnatlista").val() ; 
var dataarray=data.split(",");

$("#aihevalinta").val(dataarray);
$("#aihevalinta").multiselect("refresh");

</script>
```