# Multi column DropDown list in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Database table with two fields code and product name table have following data.

```
code 10 productName Sugar,code 20 productName  rice,code 30 productName  milk
```

I have a asp.net page with DropDownList. I want to get all data in DropDownList here is my code

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct ProductName,code from item", db.con))
    {
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(datatable);

        //   EditableDropDownList2.DataSource = datatable;

        List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in datatable.Rows)
        {
          string descr = string.Format("{0}|{1}", dr[0].ToString(), dr[1].ToString());
            list.Add(new ListItem(descr));

        }

        list = list.OrderBy(a => a.Text).ToList();
        DropDownList2.DataSource = list;

       DropDownList2.DataBind();
}
```

This code is working fine to display all productName's and code in DropDownList now what I want when I select any product in DropDownList .. only product code select in DropDownList and ProductName show in a text box I knew I'm missing something SelectedIndex change event. Please guide me how to achieve this

Comment: have a look atth answer I gave here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745204/aspdropdownlist-selectedvalues-in-multiple-selection-list/25746734#25746734 if this is what you won't I can elaborate it on your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have dropdownlist as this, note i have added selectedindexchanges and autopostback ( this is needed, because if you change something it has to postback and on selected index changed event you will be able to capture this).

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

In code behind you can write this.

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selectedProductName = ddl.SelectedValue.Split('|')[0];
        }
```

Since you are binding as plain text to listitem with format "name|id", you have to get selected value as stated above.

Suggestion -- you should bind as textfield = name and valuefield as ID.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in datatable.Rows)
            {

                list.Add(new ListItem(dr[0].ToString(), dr[1].ToString()));

            }
```

So if you follow this way, you just need to get selected product name as  "`ddl.SelectedItem.Text`".

Comment: arindam your code only show selected ProductName like sugar but i want to when i select product Sugar then dropdownlist =10 but it show Sugar  |10

Comment: @nomiikon, do you have 2 dropdownlists? i thought that, you have single dropdownlist and there when you select sugar|10, you need to show in a textbox = Sugar., Please clear the confusion.

Comment: i have only one drop down list and one text box drop list values are sugar|10  when i Select sugar|10  then text box=Sugar and drop down list show 10 (only code) not like this sugar|10

Comment: @nomiikon , you mean to say that my code which is given above is working fine, but issue is, after selection, the dropdownlist is in corrupt state i.e showing 10 not Sugar|10, right?

Comment: yes u r right now your code is good but only issue dropdownlist required when i select show 10 not sugar|10 this

Comment: So the initial code you had shown , (binding thing), you have written this on page_load right?

Comment: @nomiikon , i have tried same at my end, it works perfectly. Are you manipulating DropDownList2, anywhere in the code? Or anyother JS is accessing that changing the value?

Comment: please check this link what i want http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/multicolumncombo/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: But in your case, this is a simple dropdowlist only, you have not mentioned telerik thing in question. And if you need this kind of functionality, you need to repost your question.